# Creating variables in a function with global scope?

Tags: php

I have a function which loads a URL through a curl request, however i have read that using global is not the correct/proper way to achieve what i want to achieve.

The below code works for what i am trying to achieve, however only with the global keyword. Is this the best way to achieve this? Thanks.

```
<?php

function loadURL($feedURL, $feedName) {
global $$feedName;

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, Array(
CURLOPT_URL            => $feedURL,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
CURLOPT_ENCODING       => 'UTF-8',
CURLOPT_INTERFACE      => 'IP.ADD.RE.SS'
));
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$$feedName = simplexml_load_string($data, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

}

loadURL ("http://www.tesco.com/sitemap.xml", "TescoFeed");

var_dump($TescoFeed);

?>
```

Comment: You can just use `$GLOBALS[$$feedName] = simplexml_load_string($data, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);`  But why not just `return`?

Comment: I have tried 'return' however, it does not allow me to access the defined variable on a global scale?

Comment: Why not just create and return an associative array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using globals is often discouraged nowadays, and using variable variables is in a similar line. They're a handy tool to have, but in cases like this you'd be better to return an object with that property instead of a variable variable, for example:

```
function loadURL($feedURL, $feedName)
{
    // do stuff
    $result = new stdClass();
    $result->{$feedName} = 'your results';

    return $result;
}

$result = loadURL('foo.bar', 'TescoFeed');
var_dump($result->TescoFeed); // your results
```

I assume that you're using different variables for the result of this method so you can run multiple feeds in one process maybe, but perhaps you don't even need to differentiate the return?

```
function loadURL($feedURL)
{
    // do stuff without the name, because you may not need it!?
    return 'your results';
}

$TescoFeed = loadURL('foo.bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return the data, and assign it to a variable in the caller.

```
function loadURL($feedURL) {
    global $$feedName;

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, Array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $feedURL,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => 'UTF-8',
    CURLOPT_INTERFACE      => 'IP.ADD.RE.SS'
    ));
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return simplexml_load_string($data, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
}

$TescoFeed = loadURL ("http://www.tesco.com/sitemap.xml");

var_dump($TescoFeed);
```

This is more general because you can put the result in a variable, array, or object, or call `var_dump()` on it, etc.